# How to use multiple input and multiple output streams in a single pyspark session?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark v2.4.0 and I am reading two separate streams from kafka and doing some different transformation on each one of them, now I want to persist both the streaming data-frames, but only One of them is getting persisted and the other one does not seem to work simultaneously, would be highly grateful for any help provided.

Below is my code,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, to_date

# Created a SparkSession here, as it is an entry point to underlying Spark functionality
spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .master('spark://yash-tech:7077') \
                    .appName('Streaming') \
                    .getOrCreate()

# Defined a schema for our data being streamed from kafka
schema = StructType([
    StructField("messageId", StringType(), True),
    StructField("type", StringType(), True),
    StructField("userId", StringType(), True),
    StructField('data', StringType(), True),
    StructField("timestamp", StringType(), True),
])

profileDF = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", 'test') \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .load() \
    .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value"))

# Using readStream on SparkSession to load a streaming Dataset from Kafka
clickStreamDF = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", 'test_new') \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .load() \
    .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value"))

# Selecting every column from the DF
clickStreamDFToPersist = clickStreamDF.select("value.*")

profileDFToPersist = profileDF.select("value.*")

# Added a new column containing date(yyyy-MM-dd) parsed from timestamp column for day wise partitioning
clickStreamDFToPersist = clickStreamDFToPersist.withColumn(
    "date", to_date(col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))

# Writing data on local disk as json files, partitioned by userId.
clickStream_writing_sink = clickStreamDFToPersist.repartition(1) \
    .writeStream \
    .partitionBy('userId', 'date') \
    .format("json") \
    .option("path", "/home/spark/data/") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/spark/event_checkpoint/") \
    .trigger(processingTime='20 seconds') \
    .start()


profile_writing_sink = profileDFToPersist.repartition(1) \
    .writeStream \
    .partitionBy('userId') \
    .format("json") \
    .option("path", "/home/spark/data/") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/spark/profile_checkpoint/") \
    .trigger(processingTime='30 seconds') \
    .start()

clickStream_writing_sink.awaitTermination()
profile_writing_sink.awaitTermination()
```

**NOTE**:

1. I want both the writeStreams to write on the same path.
2. If I give different data paths in both the writeStreams then the code seems to work but the data gets persisted on different locations, is there a way that I can persist both the streams on same location, or if I can do both these transformation and persist data using single stream only as the location is same for both?
3. In one stream I am partitioning only using userId and in the other one I am doing userId + date partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as we have the same path provided for the sink directory location so output are over written.

You cannot change the "part" prefix while using any of the standard output formats.

it could be possible if you can overwrite recordWriter().

Comment: Is it possible to do both these transformations and write the dataframe using a single writeStream only?

Comment: you can use union transform on stream and then write .

Comment: how will union transform help me in dealing with both the types of partitioning as one type of data needs to be persisted with 'userId' wise partitioning and the other with 'userId + date' partitioning, I hope you understood my problem?

Comment: union work only if you have same type of data in both the result set ,in that case it is not possible to have both the data in the same place unless you recordWriter() and make it custom

Comment: thanks @sandeeprawat i managed to get 2 input streams working using union as suggested